# Circle on non plane surface in opengl

Tags: opengl

I need to draw a circle on some arbitrary non plane surface, but this circle should lay on surface and follow surface's irregular form. In other words ( that is actuially can be one of possible  solutions) want to have a "shadow" like projection on non plane surface near the mouse pointer. Do I need to create in memory a sphere and project it on the surface ? Are there some other techniques to achieve the same goal?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. First would be, to create a cylinder and intersect it with the surface, get the intersection segments, and draw them. If you already have a math library which you can leverage, and if you don't have to do intersections every frame, then this might be a good idea. You will get accurately what you want.

The other option, as you already suggested would be to use a projection. I am not sure though that, you will be able to see clearly the shadow of a circle on a surface. If however, you have parametric texture coordinates for your surface, you can create a texture with the circle imprinted on it, and apply this texture to the surface.